# Can't find params from react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a very confusing issue. I use react-navigation to navigate on my react-native app.

```
navigate('Story', { id: story.id })
```

This code works, and gives me an id that I can use on my StoryScreen

```
navigate('User', { id: user.id })
```

This code however doesn't give me an id that I can use on my UserScreen, I have tested sending an integer but it doesn't register.

Link to code: https://github.com/yarism/StoryWarsApp/blob/master/app/screens/navigation/NavigationScreen.js

UserScreen:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView,
    Image,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

export default class UserScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        this.fetchUser();
    }

    fetchUser() {
        fetch('https://www.storywars.net/api/users/' + this.props.navigation.state.params.id)
```

this.props.navigation.state.params.id is undefined

Comment: Can you provide code on your `UserScreen` and how your navigator config looks? This is not enough information for people to help you.

Comment: @hyb175 - sorry! Edited my post

Comment: Just cloned your project and tried locally. Clicking on the last button `Find writers` seems to be working fine. I got `Joakim` back.

Comment: @hyb175 - in the pushed version I have hardcorded the id since I can't access the prop. Thanks for trying it out btw!

Comment: Hmm, then i will need the exact steps for recreate the error. As without the actual code I can’t be sure where the error is. Especially, I have no clue right now where you are getting the user from in your NavigationScreen

Comment: @hyb175 - I pushed an updated version of it now. It's on Trending stories --> Any story --> The link that says Chapter 2 by {user.name}. When I start the app up it shows a red error message that says "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" but it seems like if I dismiss it I can still access the id now... I don't know if I can ignore that or if I should have a check for undefined? And I haven't gotten it to work until now, embarrassing... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking out your repo, I believe the error is with the `UserScreen` you have in your TabNav in `App.js`.

Tabviews are loaded together initially by default. At that point, there is no `params.id` in the state. One way to solve this is to have a default value for the user id somehow. There is currently no way to set a default params for scenes but you can use `screenProps` to pass something down from the navigator.
e.g.

```
const Navigator = TabNavigator({...});
return <Navigator screenProps={{ userId: 2, ...this.props.screenProps }} />
```

Then find a way to distinguish between a Profile page vs. a regular UserScreen, use `this.props.screenProps.userId` to fetch for the profile page.